# Hello i would like to connect an opcua server to and iotedge device and use the iothub direct methods to configure it

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Hello is there a tutorial or a sample i can follow to get an opc ua server configuration setup using the direct methods from an iot hub?

I have tried with the normal configuration using the published nodes.json but have not tried other ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Azure IoT Edge OPC UA module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/industrial-iot/overview-what-is-opc-publisher). This module provides a secure and scalable way to connect OPC UA servers to the Azure IoT Edge platform.

[Tutorial: Configure the OPC Publisher](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/industrial-iot/tutorial-publisher-configure-opc-publisher.md)

The above documentation explains the following IoT Hub Direct Methods that can be called from an application using the IoT Hub Device SDK:

- PublishNodes

  UnpublishNodes

  UnpublishAllNodes

  GetConfiguredEndpoints

  GetConfiguredNodesOnEndpoint

  GetDiagnosticInfo

  GetDiagnosticLog

  GetDiagnosticStartupLog

  ExitApplication

  GetInfo

Also please refer to : [Explore an industrial IoT scenario with IoT Central](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-central/core/tutorial-industrial-end-to-end.md)

Below document shows the IoTHubClient library in the Azure IoT device SDK for C in the following Microsoft documentation:

Azure IoT device SDK for C - IoTHubClient | Microsoft Docs (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-sdk-c-intro.md)

Finally, there is a great article written by Microsoft's MVP: [sandervandevelde](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/author/sandervandevelde/)
Please visit this blog: [Getting started with OPC-UA on Azure IoT Edge](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2018/11/06/getting-started-with-opc-ua-on-azure-iot-edge/)

Other Refs:
[Uses Cases of the Azure Industrial IoT Platform](https://azure.github.io/Industrial-IoT/manual/)
[image]